# multiple form input arrays issue

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form with a checkbox array which facilitates my application for the classes held in a competition and an input to enter the price of that class

So I am looping from the database the id of the row for the class which is the value for the selected checkbox (class field). Now the price isn't stored in the database so in essence it's just an input field for the user to enter in a price.

I've set the input field's name to `price[]` so it is an array of prices in the form submission.

The issue im having is iterating through the arrays with foreach loops.

```
$classes= $_POST["classes"];  == (checkbox )

$price= $_POST["price"];  == ( input text field )

my foreach is like so 

foreach($classes as $key=>$n){

          // print_r($price[$key]);

           mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_set_shows (show_id, class, price) 

                         VALUES (
                        '$showid',
                        '$n',
                        '$price[$key]')")
              or die(mysql_error().'error');            

}
```

For example, I check class options 1, 2, and 3 (in that order) and it's fine and I get the values for price and class perfectly in my table.

However if I select say classes 5, 10, and 15 together with the price input, I lose the value of price hence `// print_r($price[$key]);` which is empty if I don't follow that order.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Nice [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Even when $_POST["classes"] is an array, you will not get an associative array, and if you POST an HTML form with checkboxes unchecked, they are not posted, so you will have only the checked ones , and your array will always have positions 0, 1 and 2 if you check 3 checkboxes.

Comment: hi ...i will escape input after the testing is done mark i understand that but to be honest dont appreciate smarmy comments

Comment: hi jester so how can i make it work so if i do select class 4, 9, 10 and input the relevant price only for the checked classes any ideas ?